# Long distance US girlfriend coming to the UK

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, denial-of-entry

So last month I travelled to Los Angeles to visit my long distance girlfriend for 2 weeks, we had a great time. But now she would like to visit me in the UK.

What exactly does she need? Passport, visa etc...
She is in between jobs and is considering returning back to education at some point. She has a home lease which would prove that she has to return back to the USA.

I will be funding the entire trip. Tickets including return ticket, Reservations etc...
She'll be staying at my accommodation, I live with my dad. And we'll spend a handful of nights at Airbnbs and hotel rooms.

Will the BFO deny her entry because she isn't funding the trip herself? She's never travelled outside of the USA before so I would appreciate any advice you can provide.

Comment: Have you checked https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/tourism? USA → UK is one of the most trouble-free visa situations there is. Have her bring some proof of your sponsorship and her lease just in case, but that should be about it.

Comment: BTW, good to hear [your relationship](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/181582/287) appears to be going well. ;)

Answer (score 10):

You can find the key information for travelling to the UK on [this Gov.UK website](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control)

As a US citizen, your girlfriend

- can enter the UK visa-free and stay for *up to* six months
- will need a passport, which must be valid for the whole of her stay
- can use the UK/EEA immigration lanes and the automatic ePassport gates when clearing Immigration. This means she’s unlikely to be questioned about her stay by a Border Force officer, however she should [be aware of the Immigration Rules for visitors and have proof of your sponsorship and evidence of her intention to return to the US](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/tourism) in case she is asked
- is not automatically entitled to free [NHS care](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/how-the-nhs-charges-overseas-visitors-for-nhs-hospital-care/how-the-nhs-charges-overseas-visitors-for-nhs-hospital-care) should she become ill during her stay. She should make sure she has adequate personal health or travel insurance

Note that the UK is introducing an [electronic travel authorisation (ETA)](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/electronic-travel-authorisation-eta) for people who do not need a visa to come to the UK. US citizens don’t need one yet, but as you don’t mention the dates of her travel it’s something to be aware of.